# "Multiple Video Uploads - Incorrect Progress and Index Association in socket.on Listeners"

Tags: javascript, sockets, next.js, websocket

How can I ensure that the `socket.on('upload-progress')` listener updates the uploading progress for each video correctly when multiple videos are being uploaded simultaneously? Currently, it seems that the listener updates the progress for all videos, regardless of their respective indexes. The `handleUploadLectureVideo` function provided below is responsible for uploading the videos and handling the progress updates:

```
async function handleUploadLectureVideo({ files }: any, index: number) {
  const file = files[0];
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  formData.append("name", file.name);

  socket.emit("upload-file", {
    file,
    fileMeta: {
      originalName: file.name,
    },
    name: file.name,
  });

  console.log("index outside", index);

  // Setting video upload progress
  socket.on("upload-progress", function (data: number) {
    console.log("index", index);
    setValue(`courseLectures.${index}.uploadingProgress`, data);
  });

  // Setting video ID into payload after successful video upload
  socket.on("upload-success", function (data: any) {
    setValue(`courseLectures.${index}.lectureVideo`, data.id);
  });
}
```

Following is the backend code (Nest JS) for upload video

```
  async handleFileUpload(@MessageBody() data: any, @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
    const file = data.file;
    const meta = data.fileMeta;
    const name = data.name;
    const filename = this.getCompleteFileName(meta);
    const completePath = join('video-lectures', filename);

    await promises.writeFile(completePath, file);

    this.vimeoClient.upload(
      completePath,
      { name },
      async (uri: string) => {
        const video = new Video();
        video.url = uri;
        const result = await this.videoRepository.save(video);
        client.emit('upload-success', result);
      },
      (bytesUploaded: number, bytesTotal: number) => {
        const percentage = ((bytesUploaded / bytesTotal) * 100).toFixed(2);
        client.emit('upload-progress', percentage);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Failed because: ' + error);
        client.emit('upload-failed', error);
      },
    );
  }
```

I'm observing that the index value inside the socket.on('upload-progress') and socket.on('upload-success') listeners doesn't seem to correspond correctly to the video being uploaded, causing progress and video IDs to be assigned to the wrong videos. How can I modify this code to ensure that the correct video progress and IDs are assigned to the respective videos during simultaneous uploads?

I attempted to upload multiple videos simultaneously using the `handleUploadLectureVideo` function provided. However, I noticed that the progress updates and video ID assignments were incorrect. Specifically, the `index` value inside the `socket.on('upload-progress')` and `socket.on('upload-success')` listeners didn't match the expected video index, causing progress and IDs to be assigned to the wrong videos.

I expected that the `index` value passed to the `handleUploadLectureVideo` function would be correctly captured within the `socket.on` listeners, ensuring that each video's progress and ID updates would be associated with the correct index.

Comment: I guess the `socket.on("upload progress")` code is in the backend, may we have it?

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann, I have updated my post. Please see the backend code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, it appears the socket `"upload-progress"` event should trigger every time any video registers progress. To me, if you want to register some generic socket listeners, you should register them outside of this function using a larger scope, and use their payload to update the corresponding video upload progress with something like `{videoId: "xxx"}` or index. A work around could be to include this ID / Index in the event name string and register it dynamically in your function using `socket.on('progress-upload-${index}')`

Comment: Thanks! It worked in my case. The only thing that is remaining is that I would like to know how can I remove all of these event listeners including "upload-progress-${index}" and "upload-success" after complete upload.